# How to avoid using `reinject` in riemann clojure?

Tags: clojure, riemann, riemann-dashboard

I have riemann clojure rule as follows

```
(streams
 (where (service "a")
                #(info "a-" %)
                (moving-event-window 2 (smap folds/sum (with :service "a-derivative" reinject))))
  (where (service "b")
                #(info "b-" %)
                (moving-event-window 3 (smap folds/sum (with :service "b-derivative" reinject))))
 (project [(service "a-derivative") (service "b-derivative")]
          (smap folds/quotient (with :laa "doooo" prn))))
```

The intent is to create a sum of 2 events of a and create `a-derivative`. Similarly for service `b` to create b-derivative. I then want to find the quotient of the derived events "a-derivative" & "b-derivative".

In the above sample the `a-derivative` and `b-derivative` events are reinjected and then the I use project to get the derived events to calculate the quotient.

From the documentation of [riemann](https://github.com/riemann/riemann/blob/96c47e4d86df9b5ddc86b3131b9d59adb0a1c7ad/src/riemann/config.clj#L281-L289), it seems we must avoid `reinject`. If that is the case how do we avoid `reinject` and rewrite the above rule?

Ok, one approach I tried is as follows:

```
(streams
 (pipe -
       (splitp = service
               "a" (moving-event-window 2 (smap folds/sum (with :service "a-derivative" -)))
               "b" (moving-event-window 2 (smap folds/sum (with :service "b-derivative" -)))) 
            
       (sdo #(info "hmm" %)
            (project [(service "a-derivative") (service "b-derivative")]
                     (smap folds/quotient (with :laa "doooo" prn))))
       
       )
 )
```

And it works!. However is this right? Also this approach was easy as both functions were similar. (I.E they both relied on the `service name`, so split worked.) What if the functions were completely different.(For e.g one function relied on `service name` and another function relied on `tags` etc.)

Much help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a good use of pipe, and a fine way to solve this.